# ASP.NET MVC - How should data be modeled and retrieved for dashboard and reporting data?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model

Taking the classic example of orders etc.

Let's say you want to have a dashboard with sales data.

You want to see (and I'm completely making this up as an example):

1. Total Sales for the day (single data point)
2. Total Sales by category (in a table)
3. Top performing categories and their best sellers (in a hierarchical table)
4. Top performing sales people and their sales (in a table)
5. Sales over time (for the last day) (as a chart)

This isn't really domain data. Yes we have some elements of the domain, but it's really aggregated and massaged data.

How should I model the data for these dashboards? How should the data be retrieved from the database? What's the best practice for this type of scenario where you aren't manipulating domain objects, you are reporting on aggregated and massaged data?

In a standard scenario where you are displaying and manipulating data, an application where the domain is central, it's clear:

Define a domain model in a separate class library
Use the domain model in your View Model's to serve the data to the client.

But what about data that is dashboard data, reporting data, charts, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic scenario for [CQRS](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2013/05/04/CQRS-Explained.aspx) . The Domain model should care only about domain, not views, not dashboards, not persistence etc. For reporting, charts etc create at least one read model, which is basically a bits of the domain model in simplified (dto) form.

I say more than one read model, because it can be easier to create a read model specific for a context need, rather than one model that tries to be performant for all usages, but that really depends on your app.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the answer. Would it be ok to use datatables for some of this read model? Some of the data doesn't really map to a domain entity at all, for example a chart with sales over time. This is a simple bit of data, easily represented by a two-column table - columns Month and Sales. Would I use a datatable for that? Or create some simple read model with an entity that held a collection of SalesMonths?

Comment: Use whatever is easier for you. Tables are fine.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I have read your blog, and some other articles on the net about CQRS. Do you recommend a book or article or something else so that I can learn enough about this to start implementing it well and using it in my projects?

Comment: Not really, once you understand what CQRS is, that's pretty much it. It's a principle after all, the implementation details should be specific to your app